# When throwing an object, it only goes right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game about throwing a ball. The mouse cursor is the point, to where player should throw it.

The throwing to the right looks ok (Don't mind the force I added to the ball, it is set to low so I won't chase it for a gif purpose):
[image: Throwing right]

But when i point to the left, it still spawns the ball and the force is added to right:

[image: Throwing left]

I am wondering, how to edit my code, so the direction of a thrown ball is correlated with cursor position.

My OnFire method on Player GameObject looks like this:

```
    void OnFire(InputValue value)
{
    if(!playerHasABall) {return;}
    Instantiate(ball, ballSpawn.position, transform.rotation);
    playerHasABall = false;
}
```

And the script, that gives the ball a force looks like this (It is put on the ball GameObject):

```
{
    [SerializeField] float ballForce = 20f;


    void Start() 
    {
        Throw();    
    }

    public void Throw()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(ballForce * Time.deltaTime, 0f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    } 
 }
```

I would greatly appreciate any nudge in a good direction (No Pun intended)

Comment: `ballForce * Time.deltaTime` you need to also add a direction into this calculation. E.g.: pass it to the instantiated object (via another member variable)

Comment: So i should get mousePosition variable from Mouse.current.position.ReadValue() and calculate it like ballForce * mousePosition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code you did not point the mouse, the `new Vector2 axis (ballForce * Time.deltaTime, 0f)` always gives you the right direction and the `Time.deltaTime` factor greatly reduces the throwing power. To solve the problem, reduce the amount of power and also solve the orientation problem with the following code.

```cs
[SerializeField] float ballForce = 5f;
public void Throw()
{
    var mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    var direction = (mousePosition - transform.position);
    direction.z = transform.position.z;
    transform.right = direction.normalized;

    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.right*ballForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Comment: My man! I was thinking that i need to calculate the mouse position into the direction somehow! Thanks to you, i can finally understand it! 
I just replaced the `Input.mousePosition` to `Mouse.current.position.ReadValue()` cause i am using new InputSystem and it works like a charm! Thanks a y'all!

Comment: @Gacut Thank you and I am glad that the problem was solved. <3